# Retrieving the link to a response from a Google Form

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a script attached to a Google Form which sends a notification to a Discord channel on submission. I want to include a direct link to the individual response (link looks like `https://docs.google.com/forms/d/<myformid>/edit#response=<responseid>`). How can I retrieve that link? I get part of the link up to `/edit` with `Form.getEditUrl()` but I can't get the correct id. I checked `FormResponse.getId()` but that doesn't link me to any response.

Here's how to get to that link manually via edit form: [image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you know the response Id, you can use the geEditResponseUrl method to get the direct link to the form response. Do note that anyone with this URL can edit the response.

```
 function getEditUrl(responseId) {
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var response = form.getResponse(responseId);
  return response.getEditResponseUrl()  
}
```

Comment: I don't want to edit the response. I'm looking for a link to it with read-only access. I've added a screenshot to the OP about how to get there by hand via edit form.

Comment: @sascha_lamp, the suggested solution does not work, did you find a fix?

Comment: @Riccardo sorry, I haven't found a fix yet

Comment: Pity that the API does not expose this.... could be very handy

Answer (score 0):

You can get the responseId through the .getId() method.

```
let response = form.getResponse(responseId);
let responseId = response.getId();
```

Or if you are doing this onSubmit,

```
let form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
let allResponses = form.getResponses();
let latestResponse = allResponses[allResponses.length - 1];
let responseId = latestResponse.getId();
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is the url to the Editor of the Form opened to the correct tab

```
var responseId = e.response.getId()
var urlString = "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/" + formId + "/edit#response=" + responseId
```

The Problem is that the getId() function returns a different type of ID then the one that is generated on the edit screen.  I tried both of these examples:

```
function onFormSubmit(e){
var responseId = e.response.getId()
}
```

and from Earlking's Response

```
var allResponses = thisForm.getResponses();
var latestResponse = allResponses[allResponses.length - 1];
var responseId = latestResponse.getId();
```

They both give the same ID,  But not the required URL ID,

Here is a Snippet comparing the URLs   `https://docs.google.com/forms/d/FORMID/edit#response=ACYDBNh8k40Y7zxtUeYzw8wDwRx4pggu8APuxl5TmInVVieXN-SrmTW8tK0zHvQPmVsnYzY`
`https://docs.google.com/forms/d/FORMID/edit#response=2_ABaOnuet7P69_wc3S4QJkgkjS4abty4aDD9Zn1IQ8bhSKyGiynGGtuyg1v0A-xkLgOMelUE`

After the edit#response=  they are different.
The first one I copied from my Form editor opened to the last response.  The second is generated by the code.  It will take you to your form edit page,  but redirects to open on the first response when the url has an error.

Seems like a Bug or an Undeveloped Feature.