# Get a link to an individual Google Forms response from a Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have a Google Form which outputs responses to a Google Sheet. Some of my form questions have long paragraph responses, so I'd like to be able to click a link on each row from my tracking sheet and have it open the original response page as seen from the Form's "responses" tab.

The URL I'm trying to generate, which I get by going to **Responses -> Individual** from my Form, looks like:

```
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/<form_id>/edit#response=<response_id>
```

I have looked at the [`FormResponse`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response) API documentation, but I can't manage to extract the same ID used by the Google Form viewer from a `FormResponse` object. While I know the appropriate form ID, the response ID that is valid for that URL isn't the same one returned by either `FormResponse.getId()` or as part of `FormResponse.getEditResponseUrl()`. In other words, I can't get the data from the Forms API that's needed to generate that link. I'd rather not use edit links, which they do support generating, to view my responses.

My end goal is to have a link with the format shown above, in each row of my response form. A correct link with that format brings you to the individual response viewer page for the particular response in that row. i.e., I'd like to turn this:

```
+-----------+------------+
|Question 1 | Question 2 |
+-----------+------------+
|Long answer| Another ans|
+-----------+------------+
|One more an| Additional |
+-----------+------------+
```

Into this

```
+-----------+------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
|Question 1 | Question 2 | View link                                                  |
+-----------+------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
|Long answer| Another ans| https://docs.google.com/forms/d/abc123/edit#response=def456|
+-----------+------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
|One more an| Additional | https://docs.google.com/forms/d/abc123/edit#response=ghi789|
+-----------+------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
```

For reference, I tried generating the URL as `"https://docs.google.com/forms/d/" + formId + "/edit#response=" + responses[i].getId()`, but when visiting that URL it says the response ID is invalid.

Is there a way, either via an Apps Script or other configuration, to produce a link back to each individual response in my output sheet?

Comment: "I'd rather not use edit links to view my responses." That presumably rules out [Show URL used to edit responses from a Google Form in a Google Spreadsheet by using a script](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/89551/196152). But it's not clear to me just what you want instead. Would you please elaborate.

Comment: @Tedinoz I want to have a hyperlink from my Sheet which brings you to the view-only page for that specific response. When viewing a Form you can click "Responses -> Individual" and it shows you a rendered view of the form with a single response's content in it. You can flip through the responses/choose a particular one and it shows you that one. Each response has a unique URL, so I'm hoping there is a way to recover that URL and use it as a link.

Comment: I believe that the answer to your question is "no". Perhaps an alternative would be to display the form response in a sidebar.

Comment: If you just want to see the full answer, you can create a webpage showing all the answers in that row in the sidebar.

Comment: @Wasabi Fan By TheMaster's support, I could understand that my proposal was not useful for OP's goal. So I have to delete my answer because I don't want to confuse other users. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill.

Comment: @Tanaike I still believe it's the best alternative so far. To be clear, Whatever I commented were the OP's views and not my view.

Comment: @TheMaster Thank you for your support. I would like to modify the proposal for approaching OP's goal. When I did this, I would like to propose it. I appreciate for your always support.

Comment: @Wasabi Fan In order to correctly understand about your goal, can you provide the sample result you expect as an image and/or others? By this, I would like to confirm it and think of the workaround and solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.

Comment: @Tanaike I still don't fully understand which part you'd like clarification on, but I've done my best to improve the question. Let me know if it still isn't clear.

Comment: @Wasabi Fan Thank you for replying and adding the information. I thought that I could understand about it. So I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your goal and that was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: I too would really like a read-only link to the individual response, even after closing out editing of a form. A form is a great way to see the data collected. Another post asked this [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48368843/retrieving-the-link-to-a-response-from-a-google-form) and there is no valid solution yet it seems.Would love it if Google provided a method to retrieve this view url. The individual response url looks very different than the edit url. The view url contains the form id plus some unrecognizable identifier, which is probably the primary key of the response

Answer (score 1):

- You want to achieve to create the Spreadsheet which has the following value using Google Apps Script.

  ```
  +-----------+------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
  |Question 1 | Question 2 | View link                                                  |
  +-----------+------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
  |Long answer| Another ans| https://docs.google.com/forms/d/abc123/edit#response=def456|
  +-----------+------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
  |One more an| Additional | https://docs.google.com/forms/d/abc123/edit#response=ghi789|
  +-----------+------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
  ```
- You want to see the response page with the read only.

If my understanding is correct, how about the following workaround?

### Issue and workaround:

- The endpoint of each response cannot be directly created.
- The URL retrieved `toPrefilledUrl()` can submit. So it is not read only page.

Unfortunately, from above situations, it is required to think of the workaround. In this workaround, I used `toPrefilledUrl()` and Web Apps. The flow of this workaround is as follows.

#### Flow:

1. Create Spreadsheet by putting above ascii table.

   - Web Apps is used as the URL of "View link". And the URL retrieved from `toPrefilledUrl()` is used as the query parameter.
   - Web Apps is deployed before.
2. When users access to the link, Web Apps is opened.

   - When Web Apps is run, HTML data is retrieved from the URL of `toPrefilledUrl()`, and the submit button is removed. Then, the edited HTML is opened.

By this, the read-only response can be displayed.

### Usage:

In order to use this workaround, please do the following flow.

#### 1. Copy and paste script

Please open the script editor of the Google Form you want to use. And copy and paste the following script to the script editor.

```
function doGet(e) {
  var url = Utilities.newBlob(Utilities.base64Decode(e.parameter.u)).getDataAsString();
  var html = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url)
    .getBlob()
    .getDataAsString()
    .replace('<span class="quantumWizButtonPaperbuttonLabel exportLabel">Submit</span>', "");
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
}

function myFunction() {
  var webApps = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var items = form.getItems();
  var headers = form.getItems().map(function(e) {return e.getTitle()});
  headers.push("View link");
  var formId = form.getId();
  var responses = form.getResponses();
  var obj = responses.map(function(e, i) {
    var temp = e.getItemResponses().reduce(function(o, f) {
      o[f.getItem().getTitle()] = f.getResponse();
      return o;
    }, {})
    temp["View link"] = "=HYPERLINK(\"" + webApps + "?u=" + Utilities.base64Encode(e.toPrefilledUrl()) + "\", \"response" + (i + 1) + "\")";
    return temp;
  });
  var values = obj.map(function(e) {
    return headers.map(function(f) {
      return f in e ? (typeof e[f] == "object" ? e[f].join(",") : e[f]) : "";
    })
  });
  values.unshift(headers);

  // As a sample, it creates new Spreadsheet and put values.
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.create("sampleSpreadsheet").getSheets()[0];
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

#### 2. Deploy Web Apps

1. On the script editor, Open a dialog box by "Publish" -> "Deploy as web app".
2. Select **"User accessing the web app"** or **"Me"** for "Execute the app as:".
3. Select **"Anyone, even anonymous"** for "Who has access to the app:". This is a test case.

   - If `Only myself` is used, only you can access to Web Apps. At that time, please use your access token.
4. Click "Deploy" button as new "Project version".
5. Automatically open a dialog box of "Authorization required".

   1. Click "Review Permissions".
   2. Select own account.
   3. Click "Advanced" at "This app isn't verified".
   4. Click "Go to ### project name ###(unsafe)"
   5. Click "Allow" button.
6. Click "OK".

#### 3. Run script

1. Run `myFunction()`. By this, new Spreadsheet is created.
2. Open the created Spreadsheet.
3. Click the cell of "View link".

By this, Web Apps is run and you can see the response page with the read only.

### Note:

1. **When you modified the script of Web Apps, please redeploy Web Apps as new version. By this, the latest script is reflected to Web Apps. When the Web Apps is not redeployed even when the script is modified, the latest script is not used. Please be careful this.**

### References:

- [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
- [Taking advantage of Web Apps with Google Apps Script](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script)

Comment: Your suggestion does seem like it might be the closest alternative. It's unfortunate that there isn't true support for generating view links via the API.

Comment: @Wasabi Fan Thank you for replying. I apologize that my answer was not useful for your situation. If you want to retrieve the URL from outside, how about using Web Apps as an API? By this, for example, the URL can be retrieved by a curl command.

Comment: Yeah, that's something I'll have to investigate as the next-best thing. I'm looking for the easiest way to integrate it into my Sheet... so curl+external API itself probably isn't the best approach unless I am willing to move the operation locally, but perhaps something analogous is.

Comment: @Wasabi Fan Can I ask you about your goal of your current question? How do you want to do about the retrieved URL? If you want to put the URL to Spreadsheet, I think that Google Apps Script will achieve that. But at first, I would like to correctly understand about your goal.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to put response links in my output sheet so that it's easy to click on a row and go do the full response page. I intended to explain the use case in my question but if it's unclear I'd be happy to edit it.

Comment: @Wasabi Fan Thank you for replying. Can you provide a sample Spreadsheet that you want to put the URL? I would like to confirm it and modify the script.

Comment: Create any Form, and configure it to output responses into a new Sheet. Submit the form a few times and observe new rows appearing in the sheet. I want a link back to the response view page in each row of that sheet.

Comment: @Wasabi Fan I apologize for my poor English skill. In your replying, I cannot understand about the following points. 1. What type of Google Apps Script do you want? Standalone type or bound script type? 2. Do you know about the Spreadsheet ID that the responses are put? 3. Do you know the sheet name or the index of the sheet that the response data is put. 4. Which do you want to run the script by the trigger or do you want to independently run the script? 5. Can you provide a sample Spreadsheet you want to use?

Comment: It is a bound script in the response Sheet. So yes, I know the Spreadsheet ID. I also know which sheet I want it on and where it should go. It can be manually run. If it helps you, the problem can also be solved by suggesting a change to [this answer's code](https://support.google.com/docs/forum/AAAABuH1jm0LSKKCR3VHC8/?hl=en) where rather than linking to the edit form it links to the non-editable version. That code does what I want to do, but generates the wrong link.

Comment: @Wasabi Fan Thank you for replying. Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your replying, if you want to use the script of [the link](https://support.google.com/docs/forum/AAAABuH1jm0LSKKCR3VHC8/?hl=en), for example, how about modifying from `urls.push(responses[i].getEditResponseUrl());` to `urls.push(responses[i].toPrefilledUrl());`? If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: That's the change you suggested in your current answer. Using `toPrefilledUrl` produces a link to the editable, submittable form with the user's responses copied in. I am looking for a link to the **read-only** response page that shows what they actually submitted, all on one page. Using the prefilled URL drops uploaded files and doesn't show all sections on one page as the true form view does.

Comment: @Wasabi Fan Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot image about `page that shows what they actually submitted, all on one page.`. Can I ask you about it?

Comment: @Tanaike *Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot image about page that shows what they actually submitted, all on one page.. Can I ask you about it?* In the form edit view> click responses> You can see a page with all responses > you can navigate through  each response( the url also changes correspondingly)

Comment: @TheMaster Thank you for your comment. Yes. I had thought that OP want to retrieve the URLs for each individual response. So I proposed an answer. But at OP's latest replying, about `page that shows what they actually submitted, all on one page.`, I thought that OP's goal might be different from my understanding. if I misunderstood OP's goal, I have to remove my answer. Is my initial understanding correct?

Comment: @Tanaike Yes.That's right. Translating for OP: When op uses your workaround `toPrefilledUrl`, 1. If the form has **say, 2 sections**, your url shows the first page only. He has to click next to go to the next page. So there are **2 pages**. If he was visiting the `https://docs.google.com/forms/d/{formId}/edit#response=###`, then all item responses(for a single formresponse) for all sections are in **one page**. 2. Your url is `edit`able- OP wants **read-only**. 3. Your url drops uploaded files

Comment: @TheMaster Thank you for your detail explanation. I could understand that my current proposal was not useful for OP's goal. So I have to delete my answer because I don't want to confuse other users. For the read-only page, I think that the submit button can be removed and be disabled by HTML level. But I think that these might be not what OP want. So I remove my answer now. When I could find the complete workaround that OP wants, I would like to propose it again. Thank you for your support.

Comment: @Tanaike RE: your edit, are you sure it redirects? In my testing it seemed to redirect to the first response that the form received (not the correct one) and show an error in the corner saying "response not found".

Comment: @Wasabi Fan Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. In my environment, when I access to the URLs of "View link" on the created Spreadsheet, the page of each response can be seen. The URL is redirected. So can you provide the detail flow for replicating your situation? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: @Wasabi Fan I noticed an important. When you want to make other users show the page of URLs, please share the Google Form to users. Is this related to your current issue?

Comment: *In my environment, when I access to the URLs of "View link" on the created Spreadsheet, the page of each response can be seen. The URL is redirected*. In your ascii picture, if C2 is clicked, A2:B2 response page should show and if C3 is clicked, the answer/response of A3:B3  page should show. In my environment, (I agree with OP), *it seemed to redirect to the first response that the form received (not the correct one) and show an error in the* bottom *corner saying "response not found"*

Comment: @TheMaster Thank you for your comment. Yes. I could notice it. So I updated my answer by proposing other workaround. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: @Wasabi Fan I apologize for the inconvenience. I noticed that my latest workaround cannot be used. So I updated my answer by proposing other workaround. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and this wat not the direction you want, I apologize again.

Comment: @Tanaike It seems like a functional approach. Personally I don't think I want to go down the route of hacking together HTML and re-hosting it like this but it's a reasonable suggestion/answer.

Comment: @Wasabi Fan Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, in the current stage, in order to achieve your goal, I came up with only above workaround. This is due to my poor skill. I have to apologize for this. For example, when the query parameter for converting to read-only mode is added to the URL retrieved by `toPrefilledUrl()`, your goal will be achieved by the native functions. But in the current stage, I deeply apologize for proposing above workaround. From your replying, it seems that my workaround is not useful for your situation. If you think that my answer should be removed, please tell me.

Comment: @Tanaike The answer is good; it's the most complete solution I've seen so far and it should stay up. All I'm saying is that for my particular case I think I'm not willing to put in the effort for it right now. But for SO purposes it should stay up.

Comment: @Wasabi Fan Thank you for replying. I could understand about your replying. So I would like to leave my answer. But I deeply apologize that my proposal was not what you need.

Comment: I down-voted this answer because it is a workaround that does not solve the OP (and my) issue. There doesn't seem to be a solution (yet) that constructs the correct read-only url that looks like `https://docs.google.com/forms/d/" + formId + "/edit#response=" + responses[i].getId()` The id of the response seems to be an encoded primary key that is different than the edit url for the response id. Google needs to provide this response ID in the API.

Comment: @AdamE Thank you for your comment. Although I challenged a workaround, I could understand that it was not the direct solution. But from [the discussing with Wasabi Fan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57741469/get-a-link-to-an-individual-google-forms-response-from-a-google-sheet/57743787?noredirect=1#comment102029431_57743787), I left my answer. The reason that I cannot propose the complete answer is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for you, Wasabi Fan and other users.